# Алый и кумач

Tags: этимология

В русском языке несколько слов для красного цвета. Есть алый цвет, есть кумач.
Хотя по поводу кумача у меня подозрение, что это относится только к материи, окрашенной в красный цвет, но, опять же, интересно, почему для нее существует какое-то специальное название, а например, для синей - нет.))) А еще, если судить по звучанию, то, похоже, это тюркское слово. Я права?
И вот интересно насчет алого цвета. Это любой красный или только какой-то конкретный? И откуда взялось это название?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы правы, оба слова тюркизмы. Кумач — красная бумажная материя, алый — цвет пламени, ярко-красный.

Др.-русск. *кумачь*, впервые появилось слово в грамматиках 1696 г.; из тур., крым.-тат., тат. *kumaš* "красная хлопчатобумажная ткань", араб. происхождения;
по мнению Будагова (Словарь, 2, 64), "первоначально из арабского, на что якобы указывает специфическое множественное число от этого слова":
1. (саг., койб.) красная бумажная материя, кумач;
2. (кар. л.) красный товар;

Семёнов утверждает:

Слово «алый» известно с древнерусской поры и отмечается в письменных памятниках с XIV в. в значении «ярко-красный».
Древнерусская форма «алъ» указывает на заимствование из восточных (тюркских) языков, где основа ал со значениями «красный», «розовый», «оранжевая парча», «алый» известна с очень древнего времени. Например, татарское *ал* — «ярко-красный», турецкое *alew* — «пламя».
Скорее всего, исконное происхождение слова «алый» — доиндоевропейское, поэтому его основа присутствует во многих языках индоевропейской семьи: арабское *alaw* —– «пламя», грузинское *ali* — «пламя», персидское *ala* — «красноватый», древнеиндийское *aru* — «темно-красный». Таким образом, «алый» в буквальном переводе означает «цвета пламени».
Производное: алеть.

[**алый** | semenov.academic.ru](http://semenov.academic.ru/55/%D0)

А вообще для красного цвета много названий:

Пунцовый (от французского: *ponceau*) — густо или тёмно-алый, тёмно-багряный цвет.

Червлёный — из древнерусского: чьрвенъ, чёрмный (чермный) — тёмно-красный, кровавый.

Багровый, багряный, багрец (от древнерусского: *багръ*) — густо-красный цвет, но никак не с огненным отливом, а с едва заметною просинью.

Порфирный (от древнегреческого: *πορφύρεος*) — тёмно-красный, пурпурный, цвета порфира.
1) Порфир — общее название эффузивных кислых горных пород; цвет породы — чаще всего красновато-бурый, различных оттенков.
2) Порфир — царская регалия — длинная пурпуровая мантия.

Шарлаховый (от немецкого: *scharlach*) — ярко-красный, багряный цвет.
Шарлах – этим именем обозначается целый ряд азопигментов разнообразного химического состава, растворимых в воде, спирте с красивым ярко-красным, коричневым цветом.

Мареновый, краповый (от немецкого: *krappe* — марена) — ярко-красный цвет. Марена (крапп) — органический краситель, который представляет собой толчёный корень марены красильной — *Rubia tinctorum*.

Цветочно-ягодные оттенки красного цвета:
маковый — цвет цветущих красных маков, рябиновый — цвет спелых рябиновых гроздей, брусьяный — тёмно-красный, цвет спелых ягод брусники, клюквенный — цвет спелых ягод клюквы, цвет клюквенного сока, гуляфный (персидское: گلاب, gul‎ — «роза») — цвет спелых ягод шиповника.

Comment: Брусничный когда-то означал "зеленый", цвета брусничного листа. Сегодня постоянно сталкиваюсь с "брусничным" алым, цвета ягод брусники. Это ошибка или значение изменилось?

Comment: Хороший, интересный ответ! Поставил +1.

Одно небольшое замечание. Вот вы пишете, цитирую:

>Скорее всего, исконное происхождение слова «алый» – доиндоевропейское, поэтому его основа присутствует во многих языках индоевропейской семьи: арабское alaw – «пламя», грузинское ali – «пламя»,персидское ala – «красноватый», древнеиндийское aru – «темно-красный». 

Можно подумать, что арабский и грузинский языки - индоевропейские.

Answer (score 0):

Даль в говорах 19 века отмечал слово кумак - простая бумажная ткань обычно алого, но иногда и СИНЕГО цвета, из которой шили сарафаны.

Кумач - слово арабского происхождения (материал для одежды, ткань), в русский язык попало (17 век) при посредстве тюркских языков. Турецкое kumas - материя вообще, товар.

Переход значений "ярко-красный кумач - кумачовый цвет" возникло на татарской почве.